# How to design a power supply unit

Tags: power-supply

How do I design a power supply unit with:

```
Input: 230 Vac
Output: 5 Vdc, 500 mA
```

Use Switching Regulator for my design.

Comment: This is far too vague. You make no mention of isolation, topology, cooling, open vs. closed frame, input tolerance, output tolerance, ripple current, EMI requirements, safety requirements, reliablity requirements (MTBF), PFC ... without specific details this question should be closed, since there can be no specific answers to a non-specific question.

Comment: This is an odd question.  If you haven't a clue how to design a switching regulator unit, how on earth could the result ever be *your* design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could make the question a little more specific.

If you are looking for a general tool or guide to switch mode power supply design, there are several on the net, as well as free online design tools on the web sites of manufacturers such as:

- Fairchild Semiconductor: [Power Supply WebDesigner](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/design_tools/power-supply-webdesigner/)
- Linear Technology: [LTPowerCAD](http://video.linear.com/30)
- Texas Instruments: [WeBench Power Designer](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/analog/webench/power.shtml), [SwitcherPro Design Tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/switcherpro)

Many of these tools go as far as providing a schematic, a bill of materials,  performance parametrics and even design simulation, all for free.

If on the other hand, you would like someone to design one for you, this might not be the best place for that.

Comment: if i am using tinyCAD software for the design, how do i design the power supply unit? Any guides?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the web-based tools from the links in the answer above? That will give you a good start, then you can bring the design over to your software.